# How do wheel chair hubs/axles work?

Tags: trailer

I'm trying to build a trailer and would like to use wheels with the quick release wheelchair hub/axle mechanism. What I'm not understanding is how these would hold in the actual half inch pipe? Is there a special axle that they attach into?
https://www.bonanza.com/listings/Big-Button-Quick-Release-Axle/634239645?goog_pla=1&variation_id=861854410&gpid=319078017749&keyword=&goog_pla=1&pos=4o10&ad_type=pla&gclid=Cj0KCQiA6ozhBRC8ARIsAIh_VC0LjOKHj92CznjPkJIx45_nhlD9gO-4V-WkeJUu7QxG4-ezHIiGcWsaAg5YEALw_wcB

Comment: What's the "actual half inch pipe"? Why don't you just look at one at a bike shop to see how it works?

Comment: You're hitting up against one of the fundamental differences between bike wheels and chair wheels is that in wheelchairs the axle is only supported on one side.  This requires a solid, larger diameter axle than bikes typically use.

Comment: See https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/42490/one-side-axle-vs-regular-axle